# AngularJS Get Only Directive Attribute Names That Interpolates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-google-maps

I created [ngMap](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps),
and this directive does not watch any attribute values because attribute names are dynamic(too many cases).

However, I wanted to apply $observe to attribute **only if directive users has given the attribute values to be dynamic using double curly brackets**

I have tried [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/E1m5CgXUrSUEyTwqgXVs?p=preview) to detect if user uses double curly bracket using `compile` function and `link` function, but no luck yet.

To explain, from the following code

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div my-dir foo="{{foo}}" bar="bar"></div>
  </body>
```

I want to detect attribute `foo` value is dynamic, but attribute `bar` value is not.

I tried this code to check it, but not succeeded.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = "FOO";
});
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    compile : function(tele, tattr) {
     return {
      pre : function(scope, iele, iattrs) {
        console.log('pre', iattrs);  // this is the same as the below
      },
      post : function(scope, iele, iattrs) {
        console.log('post', iattrs);
      }
     };
    }
  }
});
```

My question is how do I detect if an attribute value is dynamic by AngularJS or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the non-interpolated value by getting the attribute value of the element itself, via `elem.attr()`.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/CqHRSKgkZpJkQ534vp2d?p=preview)**

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    var regex = /{{.*}}/;

    if(regex.test(elem.attr('foo'))) {
      attr.$observe('foo', function(value) {
        // observe
        console.log('observing foo');
      });
    }

    if(regex.test(elem.attr('bar'))) {
      attr.$observe('bar', function(value) {
        // observe
        console.log('observing bar');
      });
    }

  }
});
```